# CSharp - Store a variable name inside another variable, such that it can be called dynamically on a given object

Tags: c#

I have a bunch of data classes that implement an interface, let's call it `ISpendable`.  Depending on which `ISpendable` class is being dealt with at runtime, a controller class needs to set up different event listeners.

Example:

```
public class Money : ISpendable {}
public class Time : ISpendable {}

public class Location { public MoneyBank moneyBank; public TimeBank timeBank; }

public class MoneyBank : IBank{
    //...
    public void Spend(ISpendable money);
}
public class TimeBank L IBank {
    //...
    public void Spend(ISpendable time);
}

public class CostDisplay() {
   public CostDisplay(Location location, ISpendable cost) {}
}
```

Now what I'm wanting to do, in `CostDisplay()` is subscribe to events that occur in a specific `TimeBank` and/or `MoneyBank`, depending on the class that's implemented `ISpendable`.

So a naive approach could be:

```
if(cost is Money) location.moneyBank.AmountChanged += OnAmountChanged;
else if (cost is Time) location.timeBank.AmountChanged += OnAmountChanged;
```

But I'd rather avoid this setup as I might want to add lots more types of ISpendables.

What I need then, it appears, is to define the `.moneyBank` reference inside the `Money` class, and the `.timeBank` reference inside the `Time` class, such that I can do something like this:

```
location.<cost.DynamicallyStoredBankType>.AmountChanged += OnAmountChanged
```

It appears I can use Invoke to achieve something like this, but as far as I can tell this involves using string parsing which seems messy and potentially problematic as the codebase grows in size.

Perhaps I should just go with a simpler way?  For example, store `typeof(MoneyBank)` in `Money`, and `typeof(TimeBank)` in `Time`, and then route to the correct Bank within, say, `Location` -

```
if (type is typeof(TimeBank)) return timeBank;
if (type if typeof(MoneyBank)) return moneyBank;
```

but that doesn't feel much better than the original naive approach.

Any advice/thoughts?

Comment: Why not simply add the `AmountChanged` event to the interface? Then you can subscribe everything to the same event handler, and if needed check what is the actual type of `sender` in the event handler itself.

Comment: I guess primarily because there are potentially a large number of `ISpendable` instances, and so I don't want them all listening to all `AmountChanged` events across every IBank - I'd ideally rather only subscribe each to the relevant events.  Unless I'm misunderstanding your comment?

Comment: No, you didn't misunderstood me.

Comment: Do you have the possibility to change your class design? Because there is a strong link between MoneyBank and Money which is not designed: your design allows you to do **location.moneyBank.Spend(Time)** but it seems not suitable for the business logic (by the way it's probably a  violation of Solid's LSP)

Comment: Still at the conceptual stage so not committed to this design at all.  The reasoning behind making an ISpendable interface has been that there will be some objects that have a cost in both time and money (and anything else that might be defined), and I'd like to be able to lump all of these "costs" into a single type (ISpendable) instead of having to work with a load of parallel lists etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following advice from @Oxald, I refactored things to a bit to solve this problem.

The key was to simply add the following method to the ISpendable interface, however:

```
IBank GetRelatedBank(Location location);
```

Such that Time can return the local TimeBank, Money can return the local MoneyBank, etc.

I've slightly gotten around the problem of being able to spend Money at a TimeBank by having all objects that can be purchased implement an IPurchasable interface, which ensures that each ISpendable (cost) of that object is calling the correct bank to actually carry out the spend.  Can probably tighten  this up by changing the IBank interface to accept a type T where T: ISpendable, and then explicitly state the accepted types in each bank, eg

```
public class MoneyBank : IBank<Money> {}
```

But haven't tested to ensure this works yet.